# 'this' inside instance method in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm writing `clone` method for a `Config` class:

```
abstract class ParentConfig {
    id: string | undefined;
    name: string = '';
}

export class Config extends ParentConfig {
    version: number | undefined;
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    clone = (): Config => {
        const config = new Config();
        Object.assign(config, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this))); // this.version is undefined!!!
        return config;
    }
}

const firstConfig = new Config();
firstConfig.name = 'first';
firstConfig.version = 1;

const secondConfig = firstConfig.clone();
secondConfig.version;// undefined
```

Before calling `clone`, I can see in the Dev tool that `Config` instance has a proper `version` but new returned `Config` has undefined version.

Any ideas?

Comment: Side note: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this))` is a **lossy, slow** way to copy an object.

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdhAMID2+AZgJYDmCA3gLABQCClAJgFwKRSX60APggCu+drir5c7ANzNW+YAFtc3Xv1oBeBAHJd8pgF9mzFGgykKNBLgAeEAuwzY8hK1VqMWCAG64oMEoybnwRZRAAhGExCSkZQ1ZYMl4ReBIoAAoASnoFVh4RAAcAnMSEEyZ8lDJcBB0c7g8bLQA+PJ8klMRk620EaQB3BGbqMvzWAHkQACtceAA6Cxp8TN7PABoEACkAZUmAOQWinDBcTL3DhY0BSnIAT0yIAAtKMGyP2QQAem+EF7eC38gWC+DYGFikn4MgAhHCJgg8BARFAwesaOVKpUzN0EFRAsQyJ56gNcMNRuMmPjIKMFkpVCTdNSIAZmMzacCgmQSQBGQw4-CQHjzMjsUYk9lEmgLGrSSm9MAkZC4BbIEhjM69MVS6hAgJc-DZWS-UTiKHSdhAA) (open the console to see the result).

Comment: (I don't see why `clone` should be an arrow function instead of a method, though.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder any suggestion for clone?

Comment: For a shallow copy of enumerable, own properties: `return Object.assign(new Config(), this);`. For deep copies, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).